# ListView Odd Even row xml

Tags: android, android-listview, android-xml

This is my listview

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvRMultiple"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="52"
        android:divider="@color/white"
        android:scrollingCache="false" >

    </ListView>
```

I set row background in listview as even and odd as follows :

```
/*
 * CHANGE ROW COLOR 0 WHITE 1 GRAY
 */

if ( position % 2 == 0) //0 even 1 odd..
      vi.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.listview_selector_odd);

    else
      vi.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.listview_selector_even);
```

Now when i select an even or odd row i want the background resource to change.

So in listview_selector_odd.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/odd_row" android:state_enabled="true"/>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:state_pressed="false"/>


</selector>
```

and listview_selector_even.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/air_deezeer_row" android:state_enabled="true"/>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/even_row" android:state_pressed="false"/>

</selector>
```

when i run my listview on device and select an even or odd rows nothing happens. does someone know why and what is the correct way to do it based on my answer.

Comment: what is `vi`, and where did you put this piece of code into?

Comment: @Neoh getView of an Apdater ?

Comment: i am using getView and vi = convertView;

Comment: when you press the row, do you want its row to change color permanently, or just highlight briefly when pressed?

Comment: change permanently until another row is clicked it should be singlechoice item

Comment: Have u made an adapter for this ?? if yes.. then set the background there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think selector will be a good option for your case. Sure, you can use a selector to make it change color when pressed. Your selector will look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item 
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:drawable="@color/odd_pressed_color"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@color/odd_default_color" />
</selector>
```

but each selector row will have no knowledge of other rows. If you want a single item selected each time only, you will need to iterate other remaining row views and revert them to their default colors. It is better to put this check in your item onclicklistener:

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,int position, long id) {

        for (int i = 0; i < parent.getCount(); i++) {
            if(i != position) {
                if ( i % 2 == 1) {//0 even 1 odd..
                    parent.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.odd_default_color);
                else {
                    parent.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.even_default_color);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: yes but i want the imageview widget to change background resource not the odd even color

Comment: My example shows `color` resource. It can be drawable resource too. They work the same.